# Expresión regular para obtener texto dentro de llaves en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

Necesito una expreción regular que haga match con este ejemplo:

```
{{ texto }} {{texto}} {{texto }} {{ texto}} {{ texto texto }}
```

Que pueda saltarse los espacios entre las llaves y el texto.

Intenté de esta forma y no tuve éxito:

```
/\{+\s*texto\s*\}+/g

/{{\s*texto\s*}}/g
```

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es obtener este resultado:

```
texto, texto, texto, texto, texto texto
```

Lo harías con esta expresión regular:

```
/{{\s*([^}]+?)\s*}}/g
```

En donde hace match a todo el texto que se encuentre entre llaves. Veamos un ejemplo:

```js
let regex = /{{\s*([^}]+?)\s*}}/g;
let texto = '{{ texto }} {{texto}} {{texto }} {{ texto}} {{ texto texto }}';
console.log(regex.exec(texto)[1]);
```

Si te das cuenta, solo devuelve el primer patrón encontrado (el primer texto entre llaves). Entonces, podemos usar recursividad para que haga match a **todos** los textos que encuentre entre llaves en tu cadena y ya no solo al primero, así:

```
while (match = regex.exec(texto)) {
  result.push(match[1]);
}
```

En donde cada vez que el match encuentre un texto entre las llaves, se hace la recursividad y se vuelve a hacer match al siguiente texto entre llaves, así sucesivamente. Luego pushea ese resultado en un array, para luego concatenar sus elementos en una cadena, así:

```
console.log(result.join(", "));
```

Código completo:

```js
let regex = /{{\s*([^}]+?)\s*}}/g;
let texto = '{{ texto }} {{texto}} {{texto }} {{ texto}} {{ texto texto }}';
let match; // variable para almacenar cada coincidencia.
let result = []; // array vacío para almacenar los resultados.

// Utilizo un bucle while para buscar todas las coincidencias en la cadena de texto.
// El bucle while se detiene cuando ya no hay más coincidencias en la cadena de texto (o sea, cuando en una de ellas retorna null).
while (match = regex.exec(texto)) {
  result.push(match[1]); // extraemos el segundo elemento y pusheamos a "result", ya que devuelve => ["{{ texto }}", "texto "]
}

console.log(result.join(", ")); // del array, convertimos sus elementos en cadenas, separando cada una de ellas con ", "
```